# Interspace function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
insert :: Eq(a) => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
insert m n [] = []
insert m n (x1:x1:xs) | m==x = n : x : insert m n xs  
    | otherwise = x : insert m n xs
```

The `insert` function already works. I need help with `interspace`. The aim is that I want two write an Element between two other Elements that are given. The program is written in Haskell. The `interspace` function should write a given Element between two other given elements if they are in the list.

```
interspace :: Eq(a) => a -> a -> a->[a] -> [a]
interspace m n q[] = []
interspace m n q (x:xs)| m==x && q==(head xs)  = n: x : insert m n (headxs)++interspace m n q (xs)
    | otherwise = x : interspace m n q xs
```

Comment: Try matcing against `(x1:x2:xs)`.

Comment: What you mean exactly can you give me the new code?

Comment: The question is still bad. You should edit the first copy to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your program should look like

```
interspace m n q [] = []
interspace m n q (x1:x2:xs) | .... = ....
interspace m n q (x:xs) = x : interspace m n q xs
```